# Finding farthest valid pair in an array

Tags: arrays

For an array *A* consisting of *N* integers. I am looking to find the maximum *K* (from 0 to `N − 1`) such that there exists a pair of positions `(i, j)` satisfying `K = |i − j| = |A[i] − A[j]|`, where `|x|` denotes absolute value of x. In other words, the distance between positions is equal to the difference between values. A position together with itself (when `i = j`) is always a valid pair for `K = 0` (look at the third example).

Need some help Write a function:

```
class Solution { public int
     solution(int[] A); }
```

that, given an array A of N integers, returns the maximum possible K.

Sample Input: `A = [2, 2, 2, 1]`,
The function should return 1 as The furthest valid pair is `A[2] = 2` and `A[3] = 1`, as `1 = |2 − 3| = |2 − 1|`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do somethig like this.

```
    private static void print(int[] arr) {
    int length = arr.length;
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < length; j++) {
            if ((j - i) == Math.abs(arr[j] - arr[i])) {
                if (k < (j - i)) {
                    k = j - i;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: As u have suggested (k>(i-1)) this will NEVER enter the if condition as k=0 as our initial step. AS we are looking for maximum value. yes the solution takes 0(n^2). Please suggest if have more efficient way.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you corrected it. Earlier it was k >(j-i).
Sorry for the mistake in the comment above.

Comment: yes i have edited it. Thanks for pointing it out.